# i18n not working via php-fpm in debian

Tags: php, debian, gettext

I have a strange issue here. Here is the code:

```
 cat ./test.php
<?php

setlocale(LC_ALL,"");
//setlocale(LC_MESSAGES,'ru');
//setlocale(LC_CTYPE,'ru');
putenv("LANG=ru");
putenv("LANGUAGE=ru");

$domain = 'messages';
bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale");
textdomain($domain);
//var_dump($r);
//exit;

echo gettext("Welcome to My PHP Application");
print "\n";
echo gettext("ololo");
```

Here are localization files:

```
find ./locale/
./locale/
./locale/ru
./locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES
./locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
./locale/ru/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
./locale/en
./locale/en/LC_MESSAGES
./locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.mo
./locale/en/LC_MESSAGES/messages.po
```

When I'm executing the script via CLI, everything's okay:

```
php ./test.php
Добро пожаловать!
452231
```

But when I'm calling it from the web, I'm getting only:

```
Welcome to My PHP Application
ololo
```

What am I missing? I'm using Debian 8.6, nginx, php-fpm 5.6.29. Gettext and Intl modules are enabled in CLI and FPM configurations both.

Thanks!

Comment: BTW, the same code works pretty fine on the nearest Centos 6.6. Which makes me reeeally confused.

Comment: This might have something to do with the current working directory being different between CLI versus your web server. Have you tried looking in the error log to make sure you aren't getting any errors about missing localization files?

Comment: @S.Imp I've tried to debug fpm via `strace` and got nearly nothing: http://pastebin.com/pTG6WkBs
PHP-FPM stats the correct locales directory and doing nothing after. Can't if it trying to get any *.mo file at all

Comment: * Can't see it trying to get any *.mo file at all

Comment: Have you considered using an absolute path (or one derived from the file location) for this line: bindtextdomain($domain, "./locale");

Comment: You might also check whether putenv succeeds. It should return TRUE if it works, FALSE if there's a problem.

Comment: @S.Imp unfortunately, it seems like it works fine:( `echo putenv("LANGUAGE=ru_RU.utf8");` prints `1` and than in CLI I have localized strings and via Web only original strings:(

Comment: @S.Imp, yes, I've tried to use absolute path to the locales dir, nothing changes

Comment: does your fpm user have the rights to see the .locale?

Comment: @myxaxa yes, it looks like everything's fine with access rights. According to the `strace` output I provided before, PHP just not trying to go there for some reason

Comment: there is some diff in cli php.ini and the fpm. maybe there are not enabled the global vars set in the fmp php.ini for the putenv(...)?

Comment: @myxaxa ahahahahahahaha! Not exactly, but really close! It was `clear_env` parameter in the pool config. It was `yes` by default, which means `Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this pool configuration are added.`

Comment: @mega.venik, yeah! glad you solved it! ^_^

Comment: @myxaxa could you please make a full answer about it, so I can accept it and provide you a bounty score bonus?

Comment: @mega.venik, done. thx! ^_^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the solution was made by author:
the php-fpm.conf **clear_env** parameter was set to **Yes** by default: ***Prevents arbitrary environment variables from reaching FPM worker processes by clearing the environment in workers before env vars specified in this pool configuration are added*** it should be setted to **No**
see the manual http://php.net/manual/en/install.fpm.configuration.php#clear-env